# How to access the animation from a VRML file using three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, vrml

Is it possible to access the animation from the VRML file using three.js. With collada it works, but in the case of VRML I don't see a animation field in the event.content object.
I'm aware of this example:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/models/vrml/house.wrl

In the file are OrientationInterpolators und TimeSensors, so it must have an animation. But I don't find the corresponding HTML file. How do I start the animation from the VRML file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not implemented.
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5430

Comment: https://github.com/bartmcleod/VrmlParser now offers support for many simple animations, especially that of the house example quoted in the question. It is based on threejs.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently working on a VRML parser based on PEG.js Once that is complete, we can use the parser to generate threejs with awareness of nodes. Once we have awareness of nodes in the VRML Loader, we can convert animations. It is true that the house example has animations, but they are not parsed in the VRML loader. I think they are even commented out in the house example, because the loader can't handle them.

The parser is now in alpha and publicly available at https://github.com/bartmcleod/VrmlParser Keep an eye on when I reach the next milestones to see animations become available for ThreeJs. If the parser works on your files, all animations will already be available to you in the node tree returned from the parser, as in: Their specification is being parsed.